# Jquery DateTimePicker inline is showing blank data on first

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datetimepicker

Well I have a problem with displaying Datetimepicker from jquery-ui library.
This is the code i am using for testing

```
<input id="datetimepicker3" type="text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
            format:'d.m.Y H:i',
            inline:true
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Its working nice when i remove the inline:true, but when i add inline: true i face this problem the image.

[image: image problem]

It's empty or blank or not initialised, but when i click on any of the button such as the "home" button or as it called today button it works again and it shows the fields as in the next image.
[image: after a button click]

How can i make it visible without clicking on anything ?!
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

1- This is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/9t4kgzuf/

2- Removing or adding $(document).ready(function () is the same result

Comment: Can you replicate it in `fiddle` or `snippet`?

Comment: $(function () {..} & document.ready is same

Comment: @GuruprasadRao https://jsfiddle.net/9t4kgzuf/

Comment: @user2181397 i already tried its not working

Comment: Am sorry buddy.. Tried my best but couldn't get it to work.. May be a bug.. **[Works nice in their site](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)**.. I would suggest you to report this issue to them.. Good luck..

Comment: Can you link to the plugin you're using? It's not jquery UI datepicker.

Comment: yes it is please check the fiddle

Comment: @TJ this is the links, and btw i have the same files on my end and they are the same from the jquery-ui 

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js

Comment: Not the CDN. Where is the link to documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker3').focus(function(){
        $('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
        format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
        inline: true
      });
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I'm afraid this isn't working for me either. In any case, it does look like an attempt to hack out of the problem! @Yamen Nassif does this solution work for you?

Comment: try this here: https://jsfiddle.net/roberburnday/kbjkh1s3/ (need the css but i maked it fast)

Comment: The JS Fiddle didn't work. In the console I found this error: `injected.js:32 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "https://jsfiddle.net" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: Are you using internet explorer? Because in Chrome, Firefox, Opera & Safari works.

Comment: I'm using Chrome 60 and it didn't work again (right now). So I just checked Mozilla Firefox (v. 50.1) and it same thing happened: On focusing on the input, I get 3 ghosty links only. Clicking on any link then shows the calendar. But by the way, I thought the OP's question was about the *inline* calendar. So why do we have an input-field associated one here?

Comment: sorry, this is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/kbjkh1s3/ (a coworker try it and work in his computer).